# Close specific XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How to "rebuild" function to close specific XMLHttpRequest? I have defined variable outside function to call `xhr.abort();` everywhere I need. Now is possible, with this solution, close **last** running XMLHttpRequest if running more than one at same time - processes **before last** running are without control after replace `xhr` by re-calling `_ajax()`

```
var xhr;

function _ajax(data, callback) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', window.location.pathname, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      callback(this);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}

/* close fnc */
xhr.abort();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `xhr` as an array and store there all the requests; then you can call abort on any one of them. Like:

```
var xhr=[];
function _ajax(data, callback) {
    xhr.push(new XMLHpptRequest);
    //etc
}
xhr[0].abort();
xhr.shift(); //get rid of the aborted request
```

Comment: looks like a half way, I expected that exist some identificator inside XMLHpptRequest to defined one specific, becase this way with index.. - simply, I can't imagine being able to defined one, when elements are randomly inserted into array

Comment: This was just an easy way to keep track of all the requests. I thought you wanted to abort them in  FIFO order, and that's what push() and shift() are doing. If you could specify what order you want, I'll try to answer more completely

Comment: my request was close one specific XMLHttpRequest, but asociative array with argument in function doing what I need -> ```_ajax(data, callback, name)```  and ```xhr["namehere"].abort()``` -> so your note was useful, thanks